# How to see only hidden files in a directory?

Tags: awk

If `/dir` is the directory inside which we want to see the hidden files. Then with the below command we can achieve it.

```
ll -a /dir | awk '$NF ~ /^[\.]/ {print $NF}'
```

Comment: 1) this is not a question, 2) this won't work if the filename contains space 3) you don't need escape the `. (dot)` in `[...]`   -1 by me

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the glob you want to list directly (and the `-d` flag to prevent it from listing the contents of any globbed directories and list the directory itself instead).

```
ll -d /dir/.*
```